# retrieving cached pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple website created using JavaScript and jQuery. The website contains 4 web pages and is hosted on a web server. The issue is I want to be able to navigate through these 4 pages when I don't have access to the server (no wifi or otherwise). The way I'm linking the pages (if that has an effect) is using

```
window.location.href="page1.html";
```

the click function for one of the buttons on the home page is as so

```
    $("#btnOne").click(function() {
window.location.href="page1.html";
return false;   
});
```

I thought of using post but on the jQuery website it says "Pages fetched with POST are never cached"

Is there an effective way to accomplish what I want; having the pages cached into the browser so its available to use offline?

```
    CACHE MANIFEST
 # 01-AUG-13 215 
CACHE:

css/stylesheet.css
css/custom-theme/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css
home.html
page1.html
page2.html
js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js


    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>

</head>
```

Comment: If you temporarily change your link to a standard hyperlink e.g. `<a href="page1.html">goto page 1</a>` does this work? or does this break too?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like what you want is the [HTML5 appcache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache):

```
<html manifest="example.appcache">
  ...
</html>
```

Which lets you specify a manifest for your site and dictate what pages should be cached etc.

In the manifest file you indicate what resources you want to be cached...

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v1 2011-08-14
# This is another comment
index.html
cache.html
style.css
image1.png

# Use from network if available
NETWORK:
network.html

# Fallback content
FALLBACK:
/ fallback.html
```

There's some great detailed information over on [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) as well as some [technical gotchas](http://appcachefacts.info/) you might run into.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I actually have a cache manifest. But for some reason when I'm offline certain pages when I navigate to them it gives me the "Offline Mode. Can't browse the web" message

Comment: Are you serving the manifest file correctly with the mimetype `text/cache-manifest`? Is the file you want to navigate to listed in the CACHE section? Does it have a fallback?

Comment: yes. there's only one page that doesn't display when offline. that page is listed in the manifest and does have the "<html manifest="cache.manifest">"

Comment: Any chance you can post your manifest file code into your question? Also be sure that your HTML page that isn't working doesn't contain stuff like: `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Save the four html files and any required "resource" (javascript, css, images, etc) files on your local machine.  When you want to use your site off line, open the landing page on your local. Most operating systems, when you open (click on) and html file will run your default browser and render that page. Links will be followed to the additional pages.  This works for sites that are static (eg. html) on the server side.  They can be dynamic on the browser side.